# AngularJS - Get current object from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-material

I'm working on a user profile "card" type of thing for our application. The idea is to leverage the AngularJS Material library to create a simple interface for non admin users to manage other users assigned to them.

I have an ng-repeat running to pull the data for these cards, and then generate the markup for them, like so:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
<div class="col-md-6 md-padding float-left" ng-repeat="user in allUsers">
    <md-toolbar class="row col-md-12 md-hue-5 md-dense px-0">
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <span class="col-md-10">{{ user.name }}</span>
            <md-button id="managedUserDetails" type="submit" ng-click="null" class="md-fab" aria-label="Click to view profile">
                <md-icon md-svg-src="/images/svg/action/ic_open_in_new_48px.svg"></md-icon> 
            </md-button>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>

    <div class="row col-md-12 border border-dark">
        <div class="row col-md-12">
            <md-input-container class="md-block col-md-6" flex-gt-xs>
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <input ng-model="user.name" class="detailDisabled" disabled>
            </md-input-container>

//code continues for other bits, and yes, the tags are closed :)
```

My question is regarding the **md-button** element. In it, I would like to use a function to bring up an expanded view of that user, but to do this I need the data from the particular user card that the button lives in. Then I can use that data to populate the expanded view.

So, the question:

**Is there a way to tell Angular "Give me the data that you used to generate the parent element?"**

If not, i'll have to do some thinking, as all I can think of right now are.......non-elegant solutions :)

Comment: When you say "bring up an expanded view" what exactly do you mean? Is the data you're trying to access just the user data from the `ng-repeat`?  You could probably just replace the `ng-click="null"` with a function that takes in whatever attribute is a unique identifier for the user or the entire user object.  If you're not going to use `ng-click` then you should remove it from the button.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was intending to do, my confusion was from not understanding that I could just call the user object and get the info I needed. Glad it was simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the user object directly to the `ng-click`, using `ng-init` will call that method all the time when the element generates,

```
<md-button id="managedUserDetails" ng-click="getAdvancedView(user)" class="md-fab" aria-label="Click to view profile">
   <md-icon md-svg-src="/images/svg/action/ic_open_in_new_48px.svg"></md-icon> 
</md-button>
```

And on your controller you can access the whole user object on the button click event,

```
$scope.getAdvancedView = function(user) {
   console.log(user.name);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, of course it would have been that simple :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-init = "someFunction(user)"`

```
<div class="col-md-6 md-padding float-left" ng-repeat="user in allUsers"
     ng-init = "someFunction(user)">
```

Comment: Would that fire someFunction(user) every time ng-repeat ran, though? The docs on ng-init seem lacking (in my 5 minutes of end of day Googling)

Comment: Yes, ng-init is fine. It will be called for every ng-repeat items and call the controller function.